# Signal trap from background job without pressing enter

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, signals, trap

In Bash 5 I ran into a situation where I want to do the following:

```
trap 'echo trapped!' USR1
while true; do kill -SIGUSR1 $$; sleep 1; done &
```

But I have to press enter on keyboard every time the signal is sent to make the trap code continue.

Actually I expect the trap to be executed without any keyboard interaction.

EDIT:

Finally I got it working like this:

```
trap 'echo trapped!' USR1
while true; do kill -USR1 $$; kill -INT $$; sleep 1; done &
```

But I consider the solution as workaround and not as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone seems to have a very similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525435/how-to-immediately-trap-a-signal-to-an-interactive-bash-shell).
Long story short if it's OK to execute the command from the trap built-in in a subprocess ('echo trapped!' in this case). You can put your commands in a file (for example `a.sh`):

```
trap 'echo trapped!' USR1
while true; do kill -USR1 $$; sleep 1; done
```

and execute the file as a background process with `bash a.sh &`
If it's not okay to do it in a subprocess there is no good solution since the interactive shell does a blocking read operation while waiting for the user to enter a command and it doesn't handle most signals while that is happening (as you have noticed it does handle SIGINT). The solution above works since the trap is in a non-interactive shell (thus it is not in the middle of a blocking read when it gets the signal).